# Create a ContentProvider for using a ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

I'm developing an application that triggers some alarms, using `AlarmManager`. These alarms are based on some data stored in SQLite database (in a table named reminders).

Each time a change in the reminders table occurs, I need to remove all the alarms and add the new ones.

In order to achieve this task, I was thinking to use the [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) class, which allows to do exactly what I need, in automatic and straightforward manner.

The problem is that: In order to create a `ContentObserver` I must have a `ContentProvider`, so I should create it. But as the documentation says `"[...A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications.]"`

But, **I don't want to share data between multiple applications.**

So, can be the rigth solution to create a `ContatProvider`, only for using a `ContentObserver`?
If not, should I create my own `observer pattern` implementation for observe the change in the database?

Comment: " In order to create a ContentObserver I must have a ContentProvider " where did you  read it?

Comment: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/ I think is a good site. At the end of the page   Wolfram Rittmeyer says: ContentObservers are only for content providers.

Comment: see ContentResolver docs,  read about [un]registerContentObserver and notifyChange

Comment: Maybe I have understand what you said, but I always need to call notifyChange when I update my table, instead, implementing a class that extends the abstract class ContentObserver, I only need to override the onChange mehtod, without worring about who is modifing my data in the table.

Comment: You also need a Service to make these AlarmManager changes

Comment: who changes the remainders table?

Comment: A service that performs some update, getting data from remote server

Comment: so let it call notifyChange

Comment: I know it, but the observer patter is created for avoid this. Right? Moreover, I can avoid all these stuff and call directly the rescheduleAmars method inside my ReminderManager

Comment: notifyChange triggers all observers registered via registerContentObserver, just do quick test registering few observers and calling notifyChange

Comment: You are right, but in my case I have always a single observer.

Comment: so why do you need an observer?

Comment: Uhm, you are saying I shouldn't use it in my context?

Comment: Ok, thank you. In case I think I need more flexibility I will use a observer pattern.